# Keystore missing after importing an app

Tags: android, keystore

I was working on Eclipse Juno. It was terrible so I decide to switch to Indigo.

I imported an Android App on the Indigo, with "import" from workspace (the app was made with Juno)

Now, If i try to export the App (to do the "apk") I miss the old keystore. I remember "location" and "pass", but it looks like there isn't. What should I do?

Comment: Did you save your keystore in the project folder?

Comment: No, I did not. I believed it was already saved inside the project. 
However, I still have the old Eclipse installated.
What should I do?

Comment: Gosh, I found that file, named as the location in Juno's directory. 
I just copied it in the new eclipse directory and now it works.

Comment: @volso: I am _assuming_ that you are still testing (perhaps). But do remember for the future, if you loose the keystore file, you will not be able to publish updates to your application. The result could well be catastrophic if you have an exceptionally popular application downloaded by a lot of users. I usually keep the keystore in every single email I use and plus a copy on Google Drive, Sky Drive and every single computer I own at my offices as well as residence. Better safe than sorry eh? ;-)

Comment: I'll remember that. 
I believed it was inside the directory of the project.